# Descendent Relations + Indexing in Selenium

Tags: xpath, selenium

I'm testing a web page using selenium. I want to get all the 'leaf elements and elements which contain text'. I use the following working XPath.

```
//*[. != '' or  not(*)]
```

This works great.

But now I want to loop through each of these elements and run some command on them. I actually want to get their Position, but I illustrate my problem by using GetXpathCount.

```
int elementCount = this.selenium.GetXpathCount("//*[. != '' or  not(*)]");
for (int i = 1; i <= elementCount; ++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(this.selenium.GetXpathCount("//*[. != '' or  not(*)][" + i + "]"));
}
```

The value of elementCount is 242.
And the console output is 142 45 30 13 4 4 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... [200 other zeros]
The numbers on the console always sum to elementCount, but are always zero after ~10.

It became obvious to me that my XPath

```
//*[. != '' or  not(*)][1]
```

Does not have my intended meaning. And instead returns "all leaf elements and all elements containing text which are the first child of their parent" and is equivalent to

```
//*[(. != '' or  not(*)) and position() = 1]
```

So, I use brackets to correct this mistake:

```
(//*[(. != '' or  not(*))])[1]
```

Yay. The console output is now 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 for all elements. But let's update my looping code to actually perform an operation on the element @ path.

```
int elementCount = this.selenium.GetXpathCount("//*[. != '' or  not(*)]");
for (int i = 1; i <= elementCount; ++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(this.selenium.GetElementPositionLeft("(//*[. != '' or  not(*)])[" + i + "]"));
}
```

NO!!! GetXpathCount works but GetElementPositionLeft (and others) all fail. What gives? How can I work around this?

Here's the Selenium Exception:
{"ERROR: Element (//*[. != '' or  not(*)])[1] not found"}
    [Selenium.SeleniumException]: {"ERROR: Element (//*[. != '' or  not(*)])[1] not found"}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "ERROR: Element (//*[. != '' or  not(*)])[1] not found"
    Source: "ThoughtWorks.Selenium.Core"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selenium doesn't know what location strategy to use for `(//*[. != '' or  not(*)])[1]`. Try preceding it with `xpath=`

As an alternative locator, I got this to work with the following (in Java):

```
int elementCount = selenium.getXpathCount("/descendant::*[. != '' or  not(*)]").intValue();
for (int i = 1; i <= elementCount; ++i) {
    System.out.println(i + ": " + selenium.getElementPositionLeft("xpath=/descendant::*[. != '' or  not(*)][" + i + "]"));
}
```

Comment: N00b mistake.

Selenium assumes that it is an xpath when the starting characters are //. The function GetXpathCount also assumes all identifiers are xpaths.

My mistake was that adding the brackets around the xpath (//path) broke Selenium and now I need to add the xpath=.

Thanks